# Merge [blogspot] to [blogger]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We have [blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogger) (2017 Qs) and [blogspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogspot) (288 Qs).

According to the tag wiki of [blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogger),

> Blogger is blog publishing service by Google. *All blogs on blogger are hosted on Google server on **blogspot.com** subdomain*. You can also host with a custom domain.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The tag excerpt of [blogspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogspot) states,

> Blogspot (**also known as Blogger**) is a blog-publishing service that allows private or multi-user blogs with time-stamped entries.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

I believe it means that both refer to the same Google's blog publishing service.

Last but not least, Google redirects http://www.blogspot.com to http://www.blogger.com, so can we do the same by <s>synonymizing</s> merging [blogspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogspot) to [blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogger)?

Comment: I think as we are here to ask about programming related to use of [blogger] service and not about [blogspot] site, I suggest merging [blogspot] to [blogger] tag instead ;).

Comment: @shA.t thanks for informing me about merging! Previously I was not sure if they're the same or not... until I read [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204248/how-do-tag-merge-requests-work) :)